# About the solution of a difference equation

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $r>4$ be a positive integer. Let us consider this difference equation:
$$u_{n+1}=(1+r²ⁿ⁺¹)u_{n}-r²ⁿ⁻¹u_{n-1}+2$$

I want to find a closed form, bu I am not able to find the good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: $$u_{n+1}=(1+r^{2n+1})u_{n}-r^{2n-1}u_{n-1}+2$$
 $$(u_{n+1}-r^{2n+1}u_n)=(u_n-r^{2n-1}u_{n-1})+2$$
Find the sum of first $n-1$ terms.
Then we have a first order, first degree difference equation 
$$u_n-r^{2n-1}u_{n-1}=(u_1-ru_0)+2(n-1).$$
 Note that $2n-1=n^2-(n-1)^2,$ therefore 
$$u_n-r^{2n-1}u_{n-1}=r^{n^2}\Big(\dfrac{u_{n}}{r^{n^2}}-\dfrac{u_{n-1}}{r^{(n-1‌​)^2}}\Big).$$
$$\dfrac{u_{n}}{r^{n^2}}-\dfrac{u_{n-1}}{r^{(n-1‌​)^2}}=\dfrac{(u_1-ru_0)+2(n-1)}{r^{n^2}}.$$ Then add first $n$ terms, then you will have a closed form for $u_n$ .

Comment: @ Nilan: Does it possible to show te unicity of the resulting formula of the solution.

Comment: @ Nilan: No, I mean this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1121843/is-it-possible-to-show-the-uniqueness-of-formula-for-solution