# Show that any sequence $(u_{n})$ must tends to infinity as $n→∞$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, discrete-mathematics, dynamical-systems

The motiation to this question can be found in [About the solution of a difference equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1108853/about-the-solution-of-a-difference-equation)

My **question** is: Show that any sequence $(u_{n})$ verifying the equation in the above question must tends to infinity as $n→∞$. The expression for $(u_{n})$ is given by:

$$u_{n}=r^{n^2}\left(\sum_{m=1}^{n}\frac{u_1-ru_0+2(m-1)}{r^{m^2}}+u_0\right)$$

Comment: The other question assumes that $r\gt4$. // Actually there exists some positive constants $A_r$, $B_r$ and $C_r$ depending only on $r$ such that, when $n\to\infty$, $$u_n-r^{n^2}(A_ru_1+B_ru_0+C_r)\to0.$$ Thus, $u_n\to\infty$ if and only if $A_ru_1+B_ru_0+C_r\ne0$.

Comment: @Did: Can you elaborate with this. In particular, with the existence of those constants epending on $r$.

Comment: Hint: $$A_r=\sum_{m=1}^\infty r^{-m^2},\qquad B_r=1-rA_r,\qquad C_r=\sum_{m=1}^\infty 2(m-1) r^{-m^2}.$$