# Closed form for the summation $\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{r^{k^2}}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, closed-form

Is there any closed form for the finite sum $$\sum_{k=1}^n\dfrac{1}{r^{k^2}}$$ or infinite sum ( when $|r|<1$) $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\dfrac{1}{r^{k^2}} ?$$ While solving [this problem,](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1108853/about-the-solution-of-a-difference-equation/1108867#1108867) I found this type of finite series. But I have no idea about attempt to this problem. Thank you.

Comment: The sum can be expressed as a [theta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theta_function#Jacobi_theta_function), and that is probably the best you can do.

Comment: You got a good suggestion by the previous comment.

Comment: @Winther: Thank you. You show me a new direction. But I am not familiar with theta function. Please can you explain little bit more?

Comment: @Nilan. Same for me ... but nice pictures !

Comment: Theta functions are horrible functions with beautiful properties. Writing down the solution in terms of theta functions ($=[\vartheta(0;\log(1/r)/i\pi)-1]/2$) gives you a closed form solution that is only that. I don't think it will be very useful for calculating the sum, though it does give you access to use known properties of theta functions if you are going to continue doing stuff with the sum.

Comment: A more useful answer to your question is that your sum has no useful (in terms of evaluating it) closed form solution.

Comment: @Nilan: I have posted a partial answer to your question.

Answer (score 1):

We have

$$\sum_{k=1}^2 1/r^{k^2}= (r^3+1)/r^4$$
$$\sum_{k=1}^3 1/r^{k^2}= (r^8+r^5+1)/r^9$$
$$\sum_{k=1}^4 1/r^{k^2}= (r^{15}+r^{12}+r^7+1)/r^{16}$$
$$\sum_{k=1}^5 1/r^{k^2}= (r^{24}+r^{21}+r^{16}+r^9+1)/r^{25}$$

So, for a fixed $n$ we have

$$\sum_{k=1}^n 1/r^{k^2}= w_{n-1}(r)/r^{n^2}$$

where  $w_{n-1}(r)$ is a polynomial of degree $n^2-1$ in $r$. But obtaining the formula when $n$ goes to infinity is impossible as hinted in the above comments.

Comment: $$w_{n-1}=r^{n^2-1}+r^{(n^2-1)-3}+r^{(n^2-1)-5}+r^{(n^2-1)-7}+r^{(n^2-1)-9}+ ...+r^{2n-1}+1$$