# What is $\sum r^{an^2+bn+c}$ when $|r|<1$?

Tags: geometric-series

I was going through the properties of geometric series and the following question came to my mind. What I am willing to know is the following:

For $|r|<1$ what is the value of $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty r^{an^2+bn+c}$ with $a,b,c\in \mathbb R$ ?

I have searched in net but no positive response I have found so far. I tried to proceed manually but in vain. Can you please help me out on this matter ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $a>0.$
Since $|r|<1$ we have $$0< r^{an^2+bn+c}\le r^{An+B}$$ for some $A\in\mathbb{R^+}$ and $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}.$
Now we can apply [comparision test](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CDEQFjAD&url=http%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FComparison_test&ei=cjjrVMnwLdaSuASsnYC4Dg&usg=AFQjCNFB1iPYI4LLP1S6jpsAvRYQfoe5XQ&bvm=bv.86475890,d.c2E).

Similarly consider the case $a<0.$

Comment: Infact I tried exactly the same way and here I am stuck. If it was a sequence then we could have said smoothly the result is tending to zero but here it is a series; Comparison text will just say that it is convergent whereas I need to know the closed sum if possible to determine

Comment: I do not think there is a nice closed form. See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1117658/closed-form-for-the-summation-sum-k-1n-frac1rk2)

Answer (score 0):

For $a=\pm~b$ and/or $b=0$, we can use the [Jacobi elliptic $\theta$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theta_function): $$\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty x^{n^2}=\theta_3(0,x),\qquad\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty(-1)^n~x^{n^2}~=~\theta_4(0,x)~=~\theta_3(0,-x),$$ and $\quad\displaystyle\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty x^{\big(n+\frac12\big)^2}~=~\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty x^{\big(n-\frac12\big)^2}~=~\theta_2(0,x).\quad$ Alternately, we can also employ

approximations based on the value of the [Gaussian integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral) and [error function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function): $$\begin{align}\sum_{n=1}^\infty r^{an^2+bn+c}=-r^c+\sum_{n=0}^\infty r^{an^2+bn+c}~\approx-r^c+\int_0^\infty r^{ax^2+bx+c}~dx~=\\=-r^c~+~\dfrac12~\sqrt{-\dfrac\pi{a\ln r}}\cdot r^{-\tfrac\Delta{4a}}\cdot\text{ erfc}\bigg(\dfrac b2~\sqrt{-\dfrac{\ln r}a}~\bigg),\end{align}$$ where $\Delta=b^2-4ac.$